# How can I get Gmail to make the default address I'm sending an email from be the same as the To address in a reply?

Tags: gmail, configuration

I have two email addresses that I use with Gmail, let's call them `personal@gmail.com` and `me@mycompany.com`, the latter is integrated with SMTP and POP. When I want to send an email I can choose which email address I want to send from. Now let's say I receive an email to `me@mycompany.com` when I reply I want that reply to come from `me@mycompany.com` not `personal@gmail.com`, yet it always defaults to the `@gmail.com` address.

Is there any way to make it default to be from the "To" address in a reply?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do that from `Settings` > `Accounts and Imports` and select `Reply from the same address the message was sent to`:

[image: same address the message was sent to]

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know about that setting. Imho it should be the default.

Comment: @Adam I disagree on whether it should be default or not.. because usually you want to continue getting emails from your old accounts and replying with your official one! When you just have another account then it makes sense..

Comment: That's true. I guess it depends on how you are using your multiple accounts and I don't know how most people use it.

Comment: fyi I need to refresh gmail (I used ctrl F5) to get this setting to take effect