# Default "From" mailing address in Gmail Compose Mail

Tags: gmail, account-management

My personal Gmail account also sends and receives mail through my work address, same set-up as [this guy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13708/how-can-i-get-gmail-to-make-the-default-address-im-sending-an-email-from-be-the). When composing a *new* email, the default "From" address is my personal account. Is there any way to change the default to my business account?

Comment: FWIW, this just stopped working for me in the last week.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Goto your mail *settings*, *accounts and import* and you see "*Send mail as:*" from all your eligible mail accounts. Click the "*Make default*" link next to your desired id.

If you don't see your preferred mail id then please follow [this link](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=22370)

[image]