# Gmail: Reply as email address the message was sent to

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get GMail to make the default address I’m sending an email from be the same as the To address in a reply?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13708/how-can-i-get-gmail-to-make-the-default-address-im-sending-an-email-from-be-the)

I use different addresses in my Gmail account, for work, private matters, and a club I'm doing some work for.

Is there a possibility to automatically reply with, say, the work address to all emails that were sent to the work address and not always have to change it to the work address?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Gmail, open the settings. Choose **Accounts and Import**. There will be a list of all your Gmail accounts. At the bottom of that list will be a radio button control. One of the options will be to reply using the address that the mail came to.

Comment: wow, how could i not see this?? thanks!

Comment: fyi I need to refresh gmail (I used ctrl F5) to get this setting to take effect

Comment: absolutely have to **refresh** for this to work if you just added a new account and are testing it out