# Filter outgoing Gmail based on From address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have the following problem. Basically, I have several email accounts - one for my uni, one for my job, a personal one, etc. I primarily use Gmail, so I have all my emails redirected to this single inbox. In Gmail I have created several filters, which then filter my emails into labels, so for example mails redirected from my uni account automatically go to my "Uni" label, etc. Now this all works fine.

But, it is much easier for me to use this single Gmail account also for sending emails. Lets say I for example get an email from my colleague, which was sent to my job account and I want to reply to it. It is much easier to reply directly from Gmail. And also, this way I have all my sent emails to everybody at one place.

I have connected all my accounts to Gmail, so now I do have the option of choosing which email address I want to have in the "from" field. But, it requires me to choose it from the menu and make sure I don't forget.

**So my question is, is it possible to also create filters for outgoing messages?** To give an example. Lets say I get an email from my boss and click "reply" and it is quite likely that I forget to change the email address and he receives it from my personal address (which I don't want and also might end up in spam). And it would also save me time if I didn't have to choose all the time and would be able to set some filters.

For example all emails that I send to my colleagues at work have a particular form: i.e., name@company.com, so I would have for example a filter "if to=*@company.com", send from .,.... and same for my uni address, or have specific filters for specific people.

And **if this was not possible then at least have the possibility to automatically always "reply from" the address that it was sent to**.

I tried looking in the settings of Gmail, but couldn't find anything. I would very much appreciate if anyone knew whether it is possible and if, how.

Comment: You can't create outgoing filters, but you can default to using in the "From:" address the address that the message you are replying to was sent to. See: [How can I get GMail to make the default address I'm sending an email from be the same as the To address in a reply?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13708)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get GMail to make the default address I'm sending an email from be the same as the To address in a reply?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13708/how-can-i-get-gmail-to-make-the-default-address-im-sending-an-email-from-be-the)

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

It's not possible to apply filters to outgoing messages.

## Alternatives

1. Apply a label to your outgoing messages before you send them.
   [image]
2. See [How can I get GMail to make the default address I'm sending an email from be the same as the To address in a reply?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13708/how-can-i-get-gmail-to-make-the-default-address-im-sending-an-email-from-be-the)

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail settings

- tab Accounts and Import
- section Send mail as
- choose "Reply from the same address to which the message was sent"

Voila