# Use alternate email by default when answering a mailing list message

Tags: gmail

Suppose I have set up my Gmail account so that I can send email from my alternate address `abc@example.org`. I have followed [this procedure,](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/13713) so that when I receive a message addressed to `abc@example.org` and hit the "Reply" button, Gmail will automatically select `abc@example.org` as the `From` address.

When I receive a message sent to a mailing list I'm registered to, though, the `To` field will show the mailing list address, and not `abc@example.org`. Therefore, when I hit "Reply", Gmail will use my Gmail address as the `From` address.

Is there a mean, either by configuring Gmail, maybe with some filter options I have missed, or by using something like a Greasemonkey script, to have it automatically select the proper `From` address?

(I have looked carefully, and there is no header in list messages that actually contain `abc@example.org`, so I know this would need to be configured manually, it could not possibly just work by magic with simple option similar to the "Reply from the same address the message was sent to" option.)

Comment: @pnuts, Some mailing lists are related to personal interest and I use my private email address when writing to them, and some are professional and I use one of my professional email addresses. For some, I don't actually have a choice--for instance, I am automatically registered to my department's mailing list using my university address, and I am automatically registered to my research lab's mailing list using my lab address, which is different. And if I use the wrong address, my messages are rejected. I'm pretty sure I'm not alone in this case. :-)

Comment: @pnuts, That could work, but only if the list server is aware that `abc@gmail.com` is the same person as `abc+gef@gmail.com`. I'm not sure it's that smart. ;-) Anyhow, filtering incoming mail is quite easy, Gmail will actually do the right thing without having to explain--acting properly with outgoing mail is what is really difficult.