# Can you send emails from the Gmail task-specific email address?

Tags: gmail

I was recently introduced to the [task-specific feature](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308648?hl=en), a.k.a. the "+ email address trick", or the [Dots don't matter in Gmail addresses](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en#zippy=) features, and I learned from [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/160306/gmail-reply-as-task-specific-email-address-the-message-was-sent-to-the-tric#new-answer?s=2a283404bcb14c1daf9aa21d681190db) that you can set up a reply-as for these email addresses, but I'm wondering:

**Can you send emails with the return address being the task-specific email address?**

eg. me+stackexchange@gmail.com

Thanks!

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/87075/ricardo's answer is correct.  Can you clarify if you are making a distinction between replying to an email vs sending a brand new email?  If yes, the question title and body should be edited to clarify that as it is ambighuous given that you are sending emails when you reply to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can**.

The emails you send using the task-specific email will be sent as if they were your email address. The receiver will see the sender as the `me+stackexchange@gmail.com` account and if they reply to your email, it will be sent to that address.

The accepted answer to [Gmail: Reply as task-specific email address the message was sent to (the +trick)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160309/87075) shows you how to set it up to be a sender email. Please follow **steps 1-6**.

---

*Note*: an informed receiver could infer that your original email account is the left side of the `+` character plus the `@gmail.com` (e.g. `me@gmail.com`), but the email app won't (unless it was specifically developed to handle this).

Comment: I have added some additional generic info regarding 'send as' to the original answer in hopes of improving it. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160309/87075

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language, but I tried: _your original email account is the prefix to the left side of the `+` character plus the `@gmail.com`_ . E.g. `joedoe+amazon-shopping@gmail.com` is the task email that belongs to `joedoe@gmail.com`; that's why I said "left"

Comment: No.  You are correct.  I don't use +addressing and assumed it was the other way around.  My mistake.